# Using APC in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, apc

I want to functions like `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()` in my PHP application (I never used APC before). However, my understanding is that APC cannot be installed on PHP 5.5+ because PHP 5.5+ has its own opcode cache. If I plan on upgrading to PHP 5.5+ in the future, should I use `apc_*` functions? If I shouldn't, are there "future safe" alternatives to APC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 5.5 and onward I replaced on my [setups](https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php) APC with [APCu](http://pecl.php.net/package/apcu). APCu is APC without the opcode caching. It also provides the `apc_` functions and passes checks for `extension_loaded('apc')`.

Make sure you use at least v4.0.2 of this extension. Prior releases had a bug in which the `apc_` functions were not available even when the APC compat mode was turned on.

Also see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370586/what-to-use-instead-of-apc-user-data-cache-in-php-5-5?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

The variable storage part of APC has been left in the [APCU](http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) package. It's APC, without the code cache.